# Get display value of structured datatables cell

Tags: datatables

I'm following https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data (`"data": { "_": "phone", "filter": "phone_filter", "display": "phone_display"}`) to supply structured values for certain columns of the dataTables table, other columns are just simple:

`{"filter": "1964486", "display": "Elite 2022 Tryout ('17-'18)", "_": 1964486}`

It works fine, displays the display value, searches by the filter value. But in certain places I need to programatically obtain the full data structure (see above) from the cell. However when I try to access it through the API (let's say we are talking about the first row's 6th column's cell data):

```
myTable.cell(0, 5).data()
```

This returns only `1964486` instead of the full structure. How can I access the display value?

Answer (score 0):

`render()` can do that:

```
myTable.cell(0, 5).render('display')
```

https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().render()

It can also return filter and sort values.